# Ampscript - Dynamic content from look up table not working

Tags: ampscript, lookup-field

This is my first rodeo with Ampscript. :)

I am trying to pull in the information from a look up table (HSIcontentMatrix) to the email template that has 4 offers. If it is a specific brand I would like to pull in only that brands price from the look up table. I get all sort of errors when I try to proof it. I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Both the subscriber DE and the look up table has a field to relate it which is a column named "brand".

Each offer has:

- offer image (link to populate image src)
- Offer location
- Offer location b
- offer price
- offer link

Code:

```
%%[
VAR 

IF @Brand == "AP" THEN 
SET @offerimage1 = Lookup("HSIcontentMatrix", "offer1image, "brand", @brand)
SET @offerlocation1 = Lookup("HSIcontentMatrix", "offer1location", "brand", @brand)
SET @offerlocation1b = Lookup("HSIcontentMatrix", "offer1blocation", "brand", @brand)
SET @offerprice1 = Lookup("HSIcontentMatrix", "offer1price", "brand", @brand)
SET @offerlink1 = Lookup("HSIcontentMatrix", "offer1link", "brand", @brand) 


ELSEIF @Brand == "HSI" THEN 
SET @offerimage2 = Lookup("HSIcontentMatrix", "offer2image, "brand", @brand)
SET @offerlocation2 = Lookup("HSIcontentMatrix", "offer2location", "brand", @brand)
SET @offerlocation2b = Lookup("HSIcontentMatrix", "offer2blocation", "brand", @brand)
SET @offerprice2 = Lookup("HSIcontentMatrix", "offer2price", "brand", @brand)
SET @offerlink2 = Lookup("HSIcontentMatrix", "offer2link", "brand", @brand) 


ELSEIF @Brand == "TRX" THEN 
SET @offerimage3 = Lookup("HSIcontentMatrix", "offer2image, "brand", @brand)
SET @offerlocation3 = Lookup("HSIcontentMatrix", "offer2location", "brand", @brand)
SET @offerlocation3b = Lookup("HSIcontentMatrix", "offer2blocation", "brand", @brand)
SET @offerprice3 = Lookup("HSIcontentMatrix", "offer2price", "brand", @brand)
SET @offerlink3 = Lookup("HSIcontentMatrix", "offer2link", "brand", @brand) 

ELSEIF @Brand == "TLC" THEN 
SET @offerimage4 = Lookup("HSIcontentMatrix", "offer2image, "brand", @brand)
SET @offerlocation4 = Lookup("HSIcontentMatrix", "offer2location", "brand", @brand)
SET @offerlocation4b = Lookup("HSIcontentMatrix", "offer2blocation", "brand", @brand)
SET @offerprice4 = Lookup("HSIcontentMatrix", "offer2price", "brand", @brand)
SET @offerlink4 = Lookup("HSIcontentMatrix", "offer2link", "brand", @brand)     
    
ENDIF
]%%
```

Comment: You are missing the closing `"` after each `offerimage`. That and defining `@Brand` should get you there.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming your @brand value is the value you are pulling from the sendable DE?

If thats the case you haven't set the @brand variable with the value from the DE.

Add this in the beginning

```
SET @Brand = Brand
```

Also missing closing " after each offerimage